# visual studio 2015 debugger visualizers stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, debuggervisualizer, visual-c++-2015

Since yesterday my ability of examining STL variables and boost variables in the watch window suddenly vanished. I've searched for solutions.

1. I already looked for the options below tools-options-debugging -- e.g. use-Managed-Compatibility is off.
2. I also tried reinstalling visual C++.
3. I also tried running as admin.
4. I tried recreating the entire source tree into a fresh directory and rebuilding from scratch.
5. I also made certain, that I'm using the native debugger.
6. I reinstalled the boost visualizers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the boost version. The visualizer package had updated itself and was no longer compatible with the version of boost I was using (1.60). I've downloaded the current version (1.63) and everything started to work again.